# specify number of digits of Integer using Format VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to take an integer and display it in digits no matter what the value, e.g Int = 1 to be displayed as 001. No the integer will never be more than 3 digits. Its probably simple and im just missing the obvious.

```
CStr(Format(Int, 000)
```

I am concatenating the result as a string. Thanks

Comment: `Format` returns a string, so `CStr` is not needed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will always show three digits:

```
MsgBox Format(iMyInt, "000")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all you needed was double-quotes:

```
CStr(Format(Int, "000")
```